# Easiest way to fill a bi-dimensional int array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'd like to code a sudoku solver. The user would need to pass nine argv's to init a sudoku board like this:

```
./a.out "9...7...." "2...9..53" ".6..124.." etc..
```

I'm looking for an easy way to fill this kind of array with the passed parameters :

```
int grille[9][9] = {
    {9,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,5},
    {0,0,5,0,9,0,2,0,1},
    {8,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,2,6,0,0,9},
    {2,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,6},
    {0,0,0,2,0,0,9,0,0},
    {0,0,1,9,0,4,5,7,0}
};
```

How can I proceed ? Do I need `malloc` here ?

Comment: How about two `for` loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `malloc` to allocate the grid, just define it as a local variable in the `main` function. You need to initialize this object from the command line string arguments.

Here is a simple function to initialize a single row of the 2D array:

```
void init_row(int *row, const char *s) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        row[i] = 0;
    }
    if (s) {
        for (i = 0; i < 9 && s[i]; i++) {
            if (s[i] >= '1' && s[i] <= '9')
                row[i] = s[i] - '0';
        }
    }
}
```

You would initialize the whole grid this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int grille[9][9];
    int i, j;

    /* initialize the grid */
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        init_row(grille[i], i + 1 < argc ? argv[i + 1] : NULL);
    }

    /* output the grid */
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            putchar(".123456789"[grille[i][j]]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! This seems to be the perfect solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters strings like `9...7....` then you sould be able to read in character by character from the string.

```
for (i=0;i<9;i++)
  for (j=0;j<9;j++)
    {  
       if (argv[i+1][j]=='.') grille[i][j]=0;
       else grille[i][j]=argv[i+1][j]-'0';   //convert ascii value to number
    }
```

assuming the strings came in on the command line as you suggest

The minus '0' (ascii value 48) here is because as argv is string character '1' has code 49 so to get the value of 1 in grille you should convert from ascii code to number... -- and the dots are converted to '0' so they are caught and give number 0 in `grille` to indicate empty

Comment: Thank you very much ! That's simple and efficient !